# How to remove return statement

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Coffeescript insists on adding a return statement, how do I get rid of it?

**Coffeescript:**

```
  $('.box-menu').each (index, value) ->
    @boxes.push new LW.Box.Box @ajax, $(this).data('type')
```

**Javascript after compilation:**

```
$('.box-menu').each(function(index, value) {
  return this.boxes.push(new LW.Box.Box(this.ajax, $(this).data('type')));
});
```

Comment: Coffeescript returns the last value of a block automatically. What do you want to happen instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really, but you can structure the entire thing differently, since there's no real use for `jQuery.each` here to begin with:

```
@boxes.push new LW.Box.Box @ajax, $(elem).data('type') for elem in $('.box-menu')
```

Even if you don't do that, there should be absolutely no issue with the `return` statement here, which is why Coffeescript makes everything an expression in the first place: usually it makes no difference.

If absolutely necessary, you could do this:

```
$('.box-menu').each `function () {
  this.boxes.push(new LW.Box.Box(this.ajax, $(this).data('type')));
}`
```

Comment: Technically doesn't answer the question, but I agree it's the nicer way of doing it!

Comment: Thank you. This cleared up a lot of my questions. I like your first solution.

Comment: Using raw JS in CoffeeScript is a very bad practice. CS covers ECMA5 completely, so anything you could do in raw JS could also be done in CS.

Comment: And you're wrong telling OP that he can't get rid of `return`, because he can (see [**Matheus208**'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33417210/1202461)).

Comment: @Leonid I wouldn't really call that "getting rid of"; it's just *explictly returning a defined valued* instead of an *implicit return*... It compiles to no return statement, but that's rather coincidental.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.box-menu').each (index, value) ->
    @boxes.push new LW.Box.Box @ajax, $(this).data('type')
    return
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It does answer the question, but I think I'm going to use the non each soution.

Comment: I agree. It's much better :)